# python run time error while raw input multiple line string

Tags: python, input

I want to read multiple line input. format of input is first line contains int as no. of lines followed by string lines. i tried with

```
while True:
    line = (raw_input().strip())
    if not line: break

    elif line.isdigit(): continue

    else:
        print line
```

it prints the string lines but shows run time error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 2, in <module>
    line = (raw_input().strip())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Is it the right way to read input?
Why run time error?
I am new to python Please help me

Comment: When do you get this error?  It runs fine for me, I only get EOFError when I press ctrl-z (EOF).

Comment: @avasal: Not necessary. Empty string evaluates as False, any other string is True.

Comment: @junuxx i am also getting EOFError

Comment: @Hemc: When? Following what input? What Python version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may get a EOFError if you terminate the program with an EOF (<kbd>Ctrl-d</kbd> in Linux, <kbd>Ctrl-z</kbd> in Windows).
You can catch the error with:

```
while True:
    try:
        line = (raw_input().strip())
    except EOFError:
        break
    if not line: break
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following:

```
while True:
    try:
        number_of_lines = int(raw_input("Enter Number of lines: ").strip())
    except ValueError, ex:
        print "Integer value for number of line" 
        continue
    except EOFError, ex:
        print "Integer value for number of line" 
        continue

    lines = []
    for x in range(number_of_lines):
        lines.append(raw_input("Line: ").strip())

    break

print lines
```

This will take care of proper inputs